# How to remove special price if qty is low?

Tags: magento2, special-price

**How to remove special price if qty is low.**

***Instead of setting from and to date from advanced pricing***, I need to remove special price based on if qty is lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To customize price calculation, you need to change the code where magento calculate **final_price** in **Price Model**.

So, if you need to remove special price based on minimum quentity, you require to create new attribute for product which lets say **"Min Qty for Special Price"** and then you need to override Price.php Model and SpecialPrice.php of pricebox.

Check the below code to add attribute programatically.

**[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Setup\InstallData.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Package_Name][Module_Name]\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'min_qty_special_price',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Minimum Qty for Special Price',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => 'validate-digits',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'group' => 'Advanced Pricing'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Once you create attribute you need to override **\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php**. Check below code to override Price.php and add your custom code to calculate final price based on minimum qty that we have set using above attribute i.e. **min_qty_special_price**.

This code will use when we add product to cart and every places where magento need to calculate **Final Price** of the product.

**[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Model\Catalog\Product\Type\Price.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Package_Name][Module_Name]\Model\Catalog\Product\Type;

use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

/**
 * Product type price model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface
     */
    protected $_stockState;

    /**
     * Price constructor.
     * @param \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\RuleFactory $ruleFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterfaceFactory $tierPriceFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterfaceFactory $tierPriceFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState
    ) {
        $this->_stockState = $stockState;

        parent::__construct($ruleFactory, $storeManager, $localeDate, $customerSession, $eventManager, $priceCurrency, $groupManagement, $tierPriceFactory, $config);
    }

    /**
     * Get base price with apply Group, Tier, Special prises
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param float|null $qty
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getBasePrice($product, $qty = null)
    {
        $price = (float) $product->getPrice();

        $specialPrice = $this->_applySpecialPrice($product, $price);

        if($this->_isSpecialPriceAllowedBasedOnMinQty($product))
            $specialPrice = $price;

        return min(
            $this->_applyTierPrice($product, $qty, $price),
            $specialPrice
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isSpecialPriceAllowedBasedOnMinQty($product)
    {
        $minQtyForSpecialPrice = $product->getMinQtySpecialPrice();
        if(isset($minQtyForSpecialPrice) && $minQtyForSpecialPrice != "")
        {
            // get Current Stock Qty
            $stockQty = $this->_stockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

            // check Min Qty with Stock Qty
            $minQtyForSpecialPrice = (int) $minQtyForSpecialPrice;
            if($minQtyForSpecialPrice != 0 && $minQtyForSpecialPrice >= $stockQty)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Once you will override Price.php, you need to override SpecialPrice.php from pricing to determine whether to display special price in PriceBox or not on **Product Listing** and **Product View** pages.

**[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Pricing\Catalog\Price\SpecialPrice.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Package_Name][Module_Name]\Pricing\Catalog\Price;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Special price model
 */
class SpecialPrice extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\SpecialPrice
{
    /**
     * @return bool|float
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        if (null === $this->value) {            

            $this->value = false;
            $specialPrice = $this->getSpecialPrice();
            if ($specialPrice !== null && $specialPrice !== false && $this->isScopeDateInInterval()) {
                $this->value = (float) $specialPrice;
            }

            if($this->_isSpecialPriceAllowedBasedOnMinQty())
                $this->value = (float) $this->product->getPrice();
        }

        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isSpecialPriceAllowedBasedOnMinQty()
    {
        $minQtyForSpecialPrice = $this->product->getMinQtySpecialPrice();

        if(isset($minQtyForSpecialPrice) && $minQtyForSpecialPrice != "")
        {
            // get Stock State Object
            $stockState = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');

            // get Current Stock Qty
            $stockQty = $stockState->getStockQty($this->product->getId(), $this->product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

            // check Min Qty with Stock Qty
            $minQtyForSpecialPrice = (int) $minQtyForSpecialPrice;
            if($minQtyForSpecialPrice != 0 && $minQtyForSpecialPrice >= $stockQty)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, to complete the override, we need to specify preferences to **di.xml**.

**[Package_Name][Module_Name]\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price" type="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Model\Catalog\Product\Type\Price" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\SpecialPrice" type="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Pricing\Catalog\Price\SpecialPrice" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Totally it's called tier pricing.

It is available when you edit a product in the Advanced Pricing or under the Price field depending on your Magento 2 version

In the Tier Price area, you need to click the Add Tier button and do the following:

```
Customer Group: choose to which group this is gonna apply
Quantity: 20
Price: 100
```

Then repeat this step with the following:

```
Customer Group: choose to which group this is gonna apply
Quantity: 10
Price: 50
```

Hope this helps you.